# can python access an RSA private key stored locally in a keystore like seahorse / Apple Keychain

Tags: python, django, encryption, keystore, keychain

other than not encrypting, i have no choice but to have the RSA private key on the same system as the data encrypted asymetrically. (my system has no access to remote servers, etc) so i figured using seahorse (ubuntu) or keychain access (apple) might be useful?

is it possible to access the private key stored in one of these from python?

are there other approaches to this besides not storing the private key locally?

i need a reversible crypt so hashing is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Mac OS X, the keychain can be accessed from the shell using the `security` program. You can search for a specific private key using `security find-identity -s <search term>`, and export it to a file using `security export` (more information on those commands can be obtained from `security -h <command>`). I have not seen python bindings yet, but it should be easy to wrap the functionality you need in a `subprocess.call` call.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have chosen your answer eventhough in the end decided to use TrueCrypt...but for additional reasons that were not in my question. Even better, for the disconnected mobile devices, they now 1) load the keys into memory from a server 2) disconnect from the network 3) set off into the village to collect data ... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can there are a couple solutions for this, but so far the best one I've found is keyring.

The Python module [keyring](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) supports OSX, Windows and both Gnome keyring and KDE wallet. Just tried it out on OSX and pleasantly had no problems right out of the box. Much respect to its' author Jason R. Coombs.

The source code lives at http://bitbucket.org/kang/python-keyring-lib, but
`pip install keyring works` too.